# Объединить поля таблицы

Tags: sqlite, база-данных

Поля Фамилия Имя Отчество нужно в запросе объединить в одно поле ФИО? бд sqlite

Answer (score 2):

```
select  firstname || ' ' || lastname || ' ' || patronym from contactstable;
```

Comment: благодарю!!!

Answer (score 0):

[CONCAT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515(v=sql.110).aspx)